# Make is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I'm trying to install a rails app on Windows. When I invoke this command:

```
bundle install
```

I get this error:

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Is make on your path?

Comment: I've created new dir C:/ruby/myapp and when I typing bundle install I have this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install a **Ruby Development Kit** as described here: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

It will install a mingw environment allowing rubygems to compile binary gems for the Windows platform.

Be careful to follow the post-installation steps described in this section: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit#4-run-installation-scripts

Simply having the ruby-devkit files on your hard-drive is not enough for rubygems to make use of it.

Comment: do you see this message: "Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit..." ? If not, the devkit is not properly installed.

Comment: where I can check this message?

Comment: It is supposed to appear in the console when installing a gem like `json`. Did you follow the installation steps as described at https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit#4-run-installation-scripts ?

Comment: Another option is to use cygwin. I tried it a while back and it worked fine pretty much out of the box.

Comment: For all the scavengers, I had the same problem and as it seems whenever I tried adding DevKit to my 1.9.3. version of Ruby, it gave an info log: [INFO] Skipping existing gem override for 'C:/Ruby193', so I used --force parameter and DevKit was added correctly. Thanks @SirDarius!

Answer (score 0):

The `bundle install` commands are included with the Ruby DevKit.

Make sure that if you've correctly installed the Ruby Dev Kit (https://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/) it can also find where Ruby is installed on your HD.

When you use the command `ruby dk.rb init` you should get a message like this

```
[INFO] found RubyInstaller v2.3.3 at C:/Ruby23-x64
```

You can also use the `ruby dk.rb review` command to ensure that the DevKit has found your install path for Ruby. You should get a message like this

```
Based upon the settings in the 'config.yml' file generated
from running 'ruby dk.rb init' and any of your customizations,
DevKit functionality will be injected into the following Rubies
when you run 'ruby dk.rb install'.

C:/Ruby23-x64
```

Once you're happy with the directories specified in the config file, run the `ruby dk.rb install` command. If you're reinstalling the DevKit, you can use the -f command to overwrite anything done previously.

You should see something like this (if you used the -f):

```
[WARN] Updating (with backup) existing gem override for 'C:/Ruby23-x64'
[WARN] Updating (with backup) DevKit helper library for 'C:/Ruby23-x64'
```

Once that's done, you can check to see that your Devkit has installed properly by running the `install json --platform=ruby` command, after which you should see:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed json-2.1.0
Parsing documentation for json-2.1.0
Installing ri documentation for json-2.1.0
Done installing documentation for json after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Once your json install starts, you know your DevKit has installed successfully, which should prevent the 'make' error from occurring.