# installing rails fails, "failed to build gem native extension"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rubygems

I just installed `ruby` and `gem` on windows 10 x64, I checked that they were both installed. when I tried to install rails, it fails after a while.

see the link below for used commands

```
El Administrator: Windows PowerShell 

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ruby -v 
ruby 2.4.3p205 (2017-12-14 revision 61247) (x64-mingw32] 
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> gem --version 2.6.14 PS 
C:\WINDOWS\system32> gem install rails 
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW... 
Building native extensions. This could take a while... 
ERROR: Error installing rails: 
       ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: CuRuby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nio4r-2.2.0/ext/nio4r 
C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r asiteconf20180211-14528-1um1rd2.rb extconf.rb 

current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nio4r-2.2.0/ext/nio4r 
make "DESTDIR=" clean 
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file. 

current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nio4r-2.2.0/ext/nio4r 
make "DESTDIR=" 
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file. 

make failed, exit code 1 

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nio4r-2.2.0 for inspection. 
Results logged to C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0/nio4r-2.2.0/gem_make.out 
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: Maybe it's more of a `"Make is not recognized as internal or external command"` message issue? Have a look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19176174/1677069

Comment: Please do not post screenshots. Instead, cut and paste code, logs, etc. into the body of your question. Stack Overflow is a resource used by many over time. If your image host deletes the image, your question will no longer make sense to others who could benefit from your question.

Comment: @MarsAtomic I changed it, uploaded the image directly to Stack Overflow.

Comment: How did you install Ruby and the Rails gem?

Comment: downloaded the installer here: https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

Comment: @AndresEhrenpreis since this is ruby 2.4.x i need to use MSYS2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by using wsl. The installation process is explained [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-windows-10). I also had to use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) to enable wsl on windows 10 build 16299.192(settings > system > about). also after i installed everything I ran `sudo apt-get install nodejs` and `gem install rails`. After this, I could run the demo(`wsl> rails new demo`, `wsl> cd demo`, `wsl> rails server`).

Answer (score 2):

You need the build tools to build native extensions.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Credit: [How do I fix an error with Ruby Gems Installer on WSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54423227/how-do-i-fix-an-error-with-ruby-gems-installer-on-wsl)