# How do I fix an error with Ruby Gems Installer on WSL?

Tags: ruby, bash, rubygems, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried to install a package using RubyGems (please note that I use Windows Subsystem for Linux). I was going to install Jekyll package.

I typed `$ gem install jekyll`. After that it came up with an error:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:76: warning: Insecure world writable dir /mnt/c in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Can you please explain the error and any possible ways to fix it?

Comment: Generally there's more output after the last line: `ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`. Is there any more hints afterwards?

Comment: `current directory: /home/[user]/.ruby/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser

/usr/bin/ruby2.5 -r ./siteconf20190129-18-14vc5x8.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /home/[user]/.ruby/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
make "DESTDIR=" clean
sh: 1: make: not found

current directory: /home/[user]/.ruby/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
make "DESTDIR="
sh: 1: make: not found

make failed, exit code 127`

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the build tools needed:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: I've tried that, but when I install the package, it shows an error:
`E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.15.0-29.31_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?`
And when I try to install Ruby gem again, it shows the Failed to build the gem native extension error again.

Comment: If you run `apt-get update` followed by the command above does the error change at all?

Comment: thanks @SaraTibbetts this worked like a charm for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had to install ruby-full to get this working on WSL:

```
sudo apt install ruby-full
```